# iPhone: Send data from iPhone to mySQL with unique identifier

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, ios, uniqueidentifier

I have an iPhone app that needs to send data (it's a vote) to a mySQL server. But the user is only allowed to vote once a day and only once per user. I connect to the mySQL server by sending an HTTP request to a PHP script.

What I need is some sort of unique identifier of the iPhone the user is using. I think it's OK if the user votes twice using two iPhones, so that isn't a big concern: the purpose of the identifier is to identify each iPhone.

How can I get this? I would use [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] but I have read it is now deprecated. I have read about an open source library but it seems to have privacy leaks.

Can you guys think of any way to do this, either via XCode or via PHP? I would just keep the hasVoted BOOL in the app, but then the user can just uninstall it and make it reset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CFUUIDCreate` to make a random, unique ID. Then save the ID. Do not use  `NSUserDefaults` since it is deleted if the user reinstalls the app. I would save it in the keychain. This is not deleted unless the iPhone is wiped, and the user cannot modify the keychain.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what the "keychain" is. Could you explain that to me quickly?

Comment: The keychain is an encrypted part of the device where you are free to save passwords without fearing that they could be read by the user. The user has no way of interfacing with the keychain and its contents persist even as apps are removed, so this would be a good spot to save the unique ID.

Comment: I found this little "guide" on adding items to the keychain.
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/03/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html

It says it won't work with the simulator. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I've been able to test apps that use the keychain on the simulator. It should work unless you do something different in that tutorial.

Comment: Although it was hard to understand the keychain, I've just managed to code it and everything works. Thanks a lot :)